# Selenium TestNG reporting for multiple tests in a suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run same set of test cases in multiple browsers. For this, I have put tests(each test is for individual browser) under a suite in testng xml. After running, I get single html report from testng, If there is a test failure in one of the browser, it is not visible in report. Is there other way to handle it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Test" verbose="2" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https:test.com"/>

    <test name="Smoke_Firefox">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="test.TestLogin">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test_login"/>
                    <include name="test_logout"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Smoke_Chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="test.TestLogin">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test_login"/>
                    <include name="test_logout"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Smoke_IE">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="test.TestLogin">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test_login"/>
                    <include name="test_logout"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Add the relevant code. How are you handling multi thread access to single report file?

Comment: @Grasshopper I have added the code from testng xml.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. It had to update testng configuration in Intellijidea to get the report.